# Xiaomi Yi Video Stabilization

Tags: video, image-stabilization

I am looking for free-software to stablize video shot by Xiaomi Yi sport camera.
Ffmpeg stablization makes video look 'jelly'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to remove fish-eye effect. 
Simplest way is to set 'len rectification' on the device itself.
Then run ffmpeg video stabilizatoin (e.g http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vidstabdetect-1).

I have runned two phase stabilization (vidstabdetect, vidstabtransform ) of ffmpeg. you can see the results in YouTube:
https://youtu.be/hwSm7TppCGg